# Stored procedure works on direct database but not on web service

Tags: c#, sql, .net, web-services, stored-procedures

I have a site. It has a web service. I use many stored procedures and they all work totally fine, but this one doesn't work. When I try to run it on the Access, It works fine, but when I try to use it through the web service I get no output for any input - even when the input returned output on the direct db.

My stored procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM ShowsList
WHERE (((ShowsList.ShowName) Like '*'+['@str1']+'*')) OR (((ShowsList.ShowDis) Like '*'+['@str2']+'*'));
```

My web service function:

```
[WebMethod]
public DataSet Search(string q)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OleDbDataAdapter dr;
    OleDbCommand myCmd = new OleDbCommand("GetBySearch", this.myConnection);
    myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    OleDbParameter Param1;
    Param1 = myCmd.Parameters.Add("@str1", OleDbType.BSTR);
    Param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    Param1.Value = q;

    OleDbParameter Param2;
    Param2 = myCmd.Parameters.Add("@str2", OleDbType.BSTR);
    Param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    Param2.Value = q;

    try
    {
        this.myConnection.Open();
        dr = new OleDbDataAdapter(myCmd);
        dr.Fill(ds);
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        this.myConnection.Close();
    }
    return ds;
}
```

I have to use web service, it's a reqiuerment. I checked that the name of the sp in the db and in the function are the same and I tried many inputs of all types. Always the same result - work on the access, no output on the web service.

Comment: Try replacing " * " + ["@str1"] + " * " with " * " + @str1 + " * " (where by doublequote I mean singlequote)

Comment: Otherwise: what is the backend database? And, when you say it's a stored procedure, you mean it is scripted in the DB with something like Create Procedure GetBySearch ( @@str1  varchar(...), @@str2 varchar(...) ) As  .... ? (where by double@ I mean single@. I say, it's hard to write SQL code in SO comments)

Comment: I think I use SQL Server 2008 R2. 
I created the stored procedure, I wrote it like any other sql query - but it's saved as a sp with parameters. All my other sp works fine :)

Comment: If you're running against Ms Sql, then (1) get rid of the square brackets. Otherwise this bit: ['@str1'] will be interpreted as the name of a column in the table and (2) replace * with %. The code you have is not SQL. Google "T-SQL Like"